# CSS animation issue iOS

Tags: ios, css, animation

This code works well on Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, and MS explorer. However, it doesn't work at all on mobile devices, particularly iOS. Please let me know what needs to be added or removed to make it function properly.

HTML

```
<div class="bg-grad">
  <div class="clouds">
    <div class="cloud x1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*  BG Gradients
~-----------------------------------------*/

.bg-grad {
  background: #000;
  background: transparent url("http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Landscape_01.jpg") center bottom no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.bg-grad .bg-layer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 6;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.bg-grad .bg-layer.on {
  opacity: 1;
}


/*  Clouds
~-----------------------------------------*/

.cloud {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  background: transparent url('http://freepngimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/ten-party-balloons.png') left bottom no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .cloud {
    display: none;
  }
}

.x1 {
  -moz-animation: moveclouds 40s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: moveclouds 40s linear infinite;
  animation: moveclouds 40s linear infinite;
  width: 2036px;
  height: 1608px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 100%;

  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1400px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1400px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1400px;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r2uuvubg/2/

Comment: Could you describe how, specifically, it is not working iOS, or other mobile devices?

Comment: The animation (of balloons) from right to left is not working - you may find my jsfiddle link helpful. Thanks.